# Possible causes for "schema feature not recognized for SAX driver"

Tags: java, exception, jdom, saxparser

I am trying to execute a program developed elsewhere, and I see the following exception:

```
org.jdom.RuntimeException: http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema 
feature not recognized for SAX driver org.apache.cimson.parser.XMLReaderImpl
```

This program ran successfully a few months ago, but my development platform was rebuilt (apparently into a different configuration).  Any ideas why this program is now throwing the above exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an Xerces feature ([as listed here](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/features.html)). Thus, you need to download and put [Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org) in the classpath.

Comment: I tried that to no avail.  Any ideas why adding xerces might not help?

Comment: Likely been put at the wrong place in classpath. It must at least be *that* place from where the SAX driver is been loaded for the first time.